# How to make SWRevealViewController a child of another controller in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

Hi I've a problem I tried to solve it by reading the docs but I couldn't.

I want to the tab bar controller to be the initial VC Not the SWRevealViewController.

The issue is that the slide out menu in side the app not the first vc.
So the question how to make the SWRC there?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why could not you move your reveal view controller as a last controller in navigation queue and use your controller with "Item" menu as Sw_front? It should work.

As an alternative you can remove the whole reveal view controller from Storyboard and create it manually from your first view controller in navigation queue. And then push.

`SWRevealViewController` has a method called `initWithRearViewController:frontViewController`, and you can obtain Sw_rear and Sw_front view controllers with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` from Storyboard.

Then, when adding Item menu (manually) to navigation bar, you assign `revealToggle:` as `action` and your `SWRevealViewController` instance as `target`.

There are some variations of this approach, you can place your SWRevealViewController before the Navigation Controller in Storyboard and specify Navigation Controller as a Sw_front. Then you do not need to instantiate `SWRevealViewController` manually, but only "Item" menu.

Here could be also useful to `removeGestureRecognizers` from reveal view controller on `viewWillAppear`of intermediate view controller in navigation queue and then add back `panGestureRecognizer` and `tapGestureRecognizer` on `viewWillAppear` of the view controller with "Item" menu.

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9s3w5hp1png6g9/SidebarMenuExample.zip?dl=0) is the sample project of using SWRevealViewController in Swift with Tabbar.

I've just taken the sample project from http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/ and adjusted a little bit.

And what I dislike about using SWRevealViewController with Storyboards is that each new ViewController to be shown, has its own Navigation Controller, but if it works for you, you can keep it.

Comment: please if you can give me a source how to do it in code using swift I'm lost